# Are all isometry linear function and inversely?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, isometry

I know that all isometry ( a function that conserves length and dot product ) are linear function when you have f(0) = 0

but is the reciproque also true ?

is that true that all linear function are isometric with f(0) = 0?

Comment: $f=0$ does not preserve length.

Comment: Nor does $f(x) = 2x$.